# Android - Color taken from custom attribute returns a different value than same color from colors.xml

Tags: android, colors, attributes, hex, android-custom-view

I have a custom layout that has custom attributes, one of them being a color. I have users set this attribute to a color (not a common color) and I use TypedArray's getColor method to retrieve this color and set it to an integer (if I print this int out, it is negative). Let's say I do something like this:

```
int myColor;
TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, 0, 0);
myColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.MyView_myColor, -1);

if (myColor == R.color.special_shade_of_yellow) {
    mySpecialMethod()
}
```

Now let's say a user sets the attribute to be R.color.special_shade_of_yellow. However, the if block never goes through so mySpecialMethod() never gets called. For some reason, myColor is a negative value, while R.color.special_shade_of_yellow isn't. Why aren't they returning the same values? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors in Android can be slightly confusing. You have *color resource identifiers* (like `R.color.my_color`) and you have *color values* (like `0xff0000`), but both are represented by an `int` value.

`TypedArray.getColor()` will return a *color value*, i.e. a real color that you can directly apply to a view. Therefore, it's not something you'll want to compare to `R.color.special_shade_of_yellow` with a simple `==`.

Try this instead:

```
if (myColor == ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.special_shade_of_yellow)) {
    ...
}
```

`ContextCompat.getColor()` will resolve your *color resource identifier* (here `R.color.special_shade_of_yellow`) to a *color value*, and then you can perform an `==` comparison.